# Terraform webhook organization and token error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codepipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I'm following the instruction from HashiCorp to provision AWS CodePipeline with webhook [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline_webhook.html). I keep getting errors:

```
$ terraform plan -var-file="secret.tfvars" -out=tfplan -input=false 

Error: provider.github: "organization": required field is not set
Error: provider.github: "token": required field is not set
```

But there's no where in their documentation states where to add those fields. I've tried adding them to all the stage, or just the Source stage because that's the only time GitHub is mentioned as a provider.

I was able to provision their AWS CodePipeline without webhook [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline.html). That one has an option to do polling periodically but not instantly like the webhook option which I can use the console to set up.

For your convenience, here's the `tf` file:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "bar" {
  name     = "tf-test-pipeline"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.bar.arn}"

  artifact_store {
    location = "${aws_s3_bucket.bar.bucket}"
    type     = "S3"

    encryption_key {
      id   = "${data.aws_kms_alias.s3kmskey.arn}"
      type = "KMS"
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
      name             = "Source"
      category         = "Source"
      owner            = "ThirdParty"
      provider         = "GitHub"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["test"]

      configuration = {
        Owner  = "my-organization"
        Repo   = "test"
        Branch = "master"
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name            = "Build"
      category        = "Build"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts = ["test"]
      version         = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName = "test"
      }
    }
  }
}

# A shared secret between GitHub and AWS that allows AWS
# CodePipeline to authenticate the request came from GitHub.
# Would probably be better to pull this from the environment
# or something like SSM Parameter Store.
locals {
  webhook_secret = "super-secret"
}

resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "bar" {
  name            = "test-webhook-github-bar"
  authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
  target_action   = "Source"
  target_pipeline = "${aws_codepipeline.bar.name}"

  authentication_configuration {
    secret_token = "${local.webhook_secret}"
  }

  filter {
    json_path    = "$.ref"
    match_equals = "refs/heads/{Branch}"
  }
}

# Wire the CodePipeline webhook into a GitHub repository.
resource "github_repository_webhook" "bar" {
  repository = "${github_repository.repo.name}"

  name = "web"

  configuration {
    url          = "${aws_codepipeline_webhook.bar.url}"
    content_type = "form"
    insecure_ssl = true
    secret       = "${local.webhook_secret}"
  }

  events = ["push"]
}
```

> Update

One of the things I've tried is this:

```
stage {
    name = "Source"

    action {
        name = "Source"
        category = "Source"
        owner = "ThirdParty"
        provider = "GitHub"
        token = "${var.github_token}"
        organization = "${var.github_username}"   
        version = "1"
        output_artifacts = ["SourceArtifact"]

        configuration {
            # Owner = "${var.github_username}"
            # OAuthToken = "${var.github_token}"
            Repo = "${var.github_repo}"
            Branch = "master"
            PollForSourceChanges = "true"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code about `provider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need set the [Github provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/github/index.html) first.

Sample as:

```
# Configure the GitHub Provider
provider "github" {
  token        = "${var.github_token}"
  organization = "${var.github_organization}"
}
```

Comment: It's in stage Source. I've tried adding the `organization` and `token` there but it didn't work. Do I have to specify the provider "github" on top like that?

Comment: Where the stage comes from? codepipeline? did you have any tf file with `provider "github" {}`?

Comment: Also, please understand that I just used HashiCorp's examples. The one without webhook works just fine without the provider "github" var.

Comment: Yes, the stages are part of codepipeline. No I don't have any tf file with `provider "github"` because the other example (without webhook) doesn't need it.

Comment: This is the correct answer to your actual error that you have in the question where Terraform is complaining that you haven't defined the `token` or `organization` either in the provider config or via environment variables. If you are having multiple issues you should split your questions up or rework this question to more correctly specify the issue your answer solves.

Comment: @BMW I have a question: Is it necessary to add another provider into terraform code if you already have one provider. In this case if I have "aws" provider do I need to add "git" provider?

Comment: they are different, and case by case. for example, if you need null , template provider, terraform will auto load it when “terraform init”, but for the github provider, mostly you need set the detail

Comment: I had to add the github provider inside the module that was creating the pipeline.  Not sure why defining it my root main.tf and then expecting to to transfer did not work.  But this is definitely the solution for creating a webhook against a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem I had:

The terraform template has a var called

```
locals {
  webhook_secret = "super-secret"
}
```

That will be used to create a webhook secret with GitHub when the template is deployed. Without the `webhook_secret`. Without the `webhook_secret`, even you add provider like BMW's answer for the `token` and issue`organization`, the error will persist.

HashiCorp also recommend that creating, storing and pulling the webhook secret from the environment or something like SSM Parameter Store.

You can also check [GitHub's guide to generate and secure your webhook secret](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/) (e.g., by taking the output of ruby -rsecurerandom -e 'puts SecureRandom.hex(20)' at the terminal)

Here's the working template, I only pasted the changes, the rest (`...`) looks the same as HashiCorp's example:

```
# Input variables
variable "aws_region" {
    type = "string"
    default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "pipeline_name" {
    type = "string"
    default = "static-website-terraform"
}

variable "github_username" {
    type = "string"
    default = "nditech"
}

variable "github_token" {
    type = "string"
}

variable "webhook_secret" {
    type = "string"
}
...
# Add webhook to pipeline
resource "aws_codepipeline_webhook" "codepipeline" {
    name            = "${var.pipeline_name}-codepipeline-webhook"
    authentication  = "GITHUB_HMAC"
    target_action   = "Source"
    target_pipeline = "${aws_codepipeline.codepipeline.name}"

    authentication_configuration {
        secret_token = "${var.webhook_secret}"
    }

    filter {
        json_path    = "$.ref"
        match_equals = "refs/heads/{Branch}"
    }
}

# Wire the CodePipeline webhook into a GitHub repository.
resource "github_repository_webhook" "codepipeline" {
    repository = "${var.github_repo}"

    name = "web"

    configuration {
        url          = "${aws_codepipeline_webhook.codepipeline.url}"
        content_type = "form"
        insecure_ssl = true
        secret       = "${var.webhook_secret}"
    }

    events = ["push"]
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the error that you have in your question where Terraform is saying that you haven't defined the required `token` or `organization` either in the provider config or via environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for the notification though.